# Looking for a duology (?) with the devil as a protagonist

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a book series (a duology, I think) I read a while back. It has Lucifer as a protagonist, in a world where deities from multiple religions exist (IIRC, Lucifer's father is Chronos, a Greek deity, and he converses with Jesus and the Bhudda, among other deities). Lucifer isn't evil or the Serpent in this series, but he is distrusted, although I can't really remember why. He and his father were different in some manner, I think.

Deities can take human form, and can't be killed by mundane weapons in doing so, but they can be injured. They're more resistant to swords and the like than guns. I'm fairly certain there's a scene where Lucifer gets lethally shot by a police officer, and falls into a coma for a few days. I think that there were weapons that could kill deities, but humans wouldn't have access to said weapons under normal circumstances.

I think the ultimate antagonist was Pandora's box.

I read it probably over 5 years ago, and judging from my reading habits back then, it wasn't a new release. I read it in English, and I don't think it was translated from another language. I think I read the books in paperback, but I don't really remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Waywalkers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/70951.Waywalkers)

According to the Goodreads description, Lucifer is the protagonist. He’s also the son of Time, so there’s Chronos right there:

> Sam Linnifer works part-time at a London university as a translator of
>   obscure ancient texts. He’s a quiet fellow with a few friends and an
>   affection for cats. He’s also immortal and the Son of Time. You might
>   know him better as Lucifer, the Devourer of Souls, or the Devil. And
>   with all the gods in Heaven about to go to war over the ownership of
>   Earth, you’re going to be extremely glad he’s not exactly who legend
>   makes him out to be.

We’ve got the whole cast (Buddha etc.)

> Webb draws from several mythologies for this series in a kind of
>   religious free-for-all. We get Jehovah, Lucifer, archangels, and the
>   denizens of Hell. In addition to these Judeo-Christian staples, the
>   Scandanavian gods of Valhalla, Egyptian Seth, Greek Cronus and Buddha
>   also make appearances. Rather than being seperate groups they are all
>   part of the same family, spawned from personified concepts like Time,
>   Wisdom, Love and Magic. Also included are the fey folk of many
>   cultures. It makes a colourful collection for worldbuilding and Webb
>   does a good job of tying it all together.

The main antagonist are the “Pandora spirits,” as indicated in the question.